# Please help me calculating $\lim_{(x,y)\to (-3,2)}\frac{y-2}{x+3}$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

> I need to solve this.
>   It's my first time.
>   I tried but ...

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to (-3,2)}\frac{y-2}{x+3}$$

Comment: Some guesses? ${}$

Comment: This limit does not exist. Are you sure that this is what you are asked to do? Or do you want to prove/disprove that it exists?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Choose for example the path $\;y=x+5\;$ , then we get the limit

$$\lim_{x\to-3}\frac{x+5-2}{x+3}=1$$

Now choose the path $\;y=2,\,x\to-3\;$ , then we get

$$\lim_{x\to-3}\frac{2-2}{x+3}=0$$

and thus the limit doesn't exist.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:** Consider the limit along the path $y = \alpha(x + 3) + 2$ for various $\alpha\in\Bbb R$.

Comment: For whatever reason I much prefer answers which do not resort to the limit blowing up. (+1)

Answer (score 0):

A point in direction $\theta_0$ from $(-3,2)$ at distance $d$ is given by the coordinates $(-3+d\cos\theta,2+d\sin\theta)$.

Plugging in the function, you get

$$\lim_{(d,\theta)\to(0,\theta_0)}\frac{d\sin\theta}{d\cos\theta}=\tan\theta_0,$$ which obviously doesn't have a single value.